# Eclipse: possible to SVN commit to the master project while committing a sub-project?

Tags: eclipse, svn, svn-externals

In my project I have a directory structure like this :

```
  project
    --common
    --subproject
      --common      (junction, not a copy)
```

The subproject needs some files from `common`. Therefore I created a 'junction' (in XP using the sysinternals command) to be able to see and make changes in `common` from within the subproject.

This works like a charm, any changes to both commons are immediately on both `common` since in fact it points to the same folder.

Then I made a separate project in Eclipse for the subproject folder and its own svn repository.

But when I want to commit the subproject, it wants to commit the 'common' folder as if it were a real folder, but in fact this folder needs to be committed only to its parents repository!

Is there a way of telling svn to make commits to a different repository than its own?

`svn:externals` is not a good solution since this creates duplicate sources, and makes it even harder to maintain, because it's not automatically kept in sync.

Comment: `svn:externals` should be the good solution, it is kept in sync automatically, and you can commit changes in both repositories in one eclipse commit.... Did you set your `svn:externals` with a fixed revision, that could explain why it is a so bad solution for you.

Comment: It works, but svn:externals creates duplicate sources, which is not really what I want, since there's a large framework of 400MB in 'common' (almost every big Javascript library you can think of), which now takes up 1600MB on disk (incl. .svn folders)!  The junction way seemed nice, but doesn't play nicely with svn, I guess...

Comment: I meant it's not automatically synced, because this only happens when you commit/update, not 'real time'.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse's file system abstraction features [linked folders](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-45.htm).

Have you tried using those rather than a junction at the filesystem level? (I don't know how  the subversion plugin treats those, but perhaps you are in luck)

Comment: linked folders are ignored during an svn-commit, so this is not really a solution, I think...